# How to create MultiSever and create links between them

Tags: java, database, multithreading, sockets, model-view-controller

Someone can help me, im making a chat app by java , it have multi server and multi  client, MVC code structure, and it have database. So many example of java about chat client-server on google  but dont have Multil server and make links between them. 
Can some give me a guide to make Multil server and links between them.  some example about MVC and JDBC
Thanks you
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, you can create a chat by saving the messages in the DB or using socket and things like. Can you try to clear only the question with only what you want and remove useless informations?

Comment: i made chat app with one server and multi client, and now I DONT KNOW HOW TO MAKE MULTIL SERVER(and having links between them such as share data,...) In my app, i wanna each 1 sever only allow 2 client connect in same time, if over, auto move another server . Thanks That All :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a diagram for a MVC from [this](http://withfriendship.com/user/aligra/model-view-controller.php) site.[image: model view controller]

You will need to start with separate classes for each component, `Server, Client, View` etc. 
You will need to connect the components together by using **sockets**. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) are some Java docs for sockets on how they connect two programs (or classes) together.
That should help you get started to make a program that can read and write data from one component to the other. From here you can go on to connect your database using JDBC and access it from the Server.

[This](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=25&video=17767) is also a great tutorial from Bucky of thenewboston on making a simple chat system using sockets.